‘service’ has not been declared in 'namespace’
I made this simple proto file and compiled it with protoc(3.19.6).
But when i checked the pb.h i couldn't find Calculator declared in helloworld(namespace).
What should i do? i need to use "using namespace helloworld::Calculator" in grpc code.
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

service Calculator
{
  rpc Add (AddRequest) returns (AddReply) {}
}

message AddRequest
{
  int32 a = 1;
  int32 b = 2;
}

message AddReply
{
  int32 result = 1;
}

I searched on Google and asked GPT, but I couldn't find the answer.

Please update your question to include the specific protoc command that you ran. You wrote that you "checked pb.h" so I assume you're using C++. I suspect that you aren't using gRPC correctly. gRPC (and specifically its use of service and rpc in protobuf messages) leverages protobuf but requires additional tooling. See C++ Quickstart
